# AngularJS formatting data based on array of key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the HTML with Angular below, that simply loops through each result and prints it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactions | filter:search">
    <td>{{transaction.created}}</td>
    <td><a href="#/transactions/{{transaction.id}}">{{transaction.type}}</a></td>
    <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

However, the database values of `type` are send, receive, buy, and sell.  When it's displayed in the view,  I want it to be as you could expect, a verb (sent, received, bought, sold).

How can I create a JavaScript array with key-value pairs of db value to display value, and display the value from that array where it matches the key (in Angular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `types` that you are getting are something like:

- 200 for sent
- 150 for received
- 25 for bought
- 354 for sold

You could just create a simple filter, like this:

```
app.filter('typeToString', function(){
    var types = {'200':'sent', '150':'received', '25':'bought', '354':'sold'};
    return function(type){
         return types[type];
    };
})
```

And use it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactions | filter:search">
    <td>{{transaction.created}}</td>
    <td><a href="#/transactions/{{transaction.id}}">{{transaction.type|typeToString}}</a></td>
    <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zdLwbnhL/)

On the other hand, if the `types` that you are getting are something like:

- 0 for sent
- 1 for received
- 2 for bought
- 3 for sold

Then your filter could be like this:

```
app.filter('typeToString', function(){
    var types = ['sent', 'received', 'bought', 'sold'];
    return function(type){
         return types[type];            
    };
})
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zdLwbnhL/1/)

Comment: Not working -- nothing is being shown in the table for the value.

Comment: @BillyAssim I just made another update with another working example for the other case, have a look at it because this works. If it still doesn't work for you, share the code that you are using and I will help you to make it work, thanks!